# How to select one value of a data.frame within a list column with R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that contains a  type column. The list contains a 1x3 data.frame. I only want one value from this list. Thus will flatten my data.frame so I can write out a csv.

How do I select one item from the nested data.frame (see the 2nd column)? [image: screenshot]

Here's the nested col. I'd provide the data but cannot flatten to write_csv.

[image]

result of dput:

```
structure(list(id = c("1386707", "1386700", "1386462", "1386340", 
"1386246", "1386300"), fields.created = c("2020-05-07T02:09:27.000-0700", 
"2020-05-07T01:20:11.000-0700", "2020-05-06T21:38:14.000-0700", 
"2020-05-06T07:19:44.000-0700", "2020-05-06T06:11:43.000-0700", 
"2020-05-06T02:26:44.000-0700"), fields.customfield_10303 = c(NA, 
NA, 3, 3, NA, NA), fields.customfield_28100 = list(NULL, structure(list(
    self = ".../rest/api/2/customFieldOption/76412", 
    value = "New Feature", id = "76412"), .Names = c("self", 
"value", "id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
    self = ".../rest/api/2/customFieldOption/76414", 
    value = "Technical Debt", id = "76414"), .Names = c("self", 
"value", "id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), NULL, 
    structure(list(self = ".../rest/api/2/customFieldOption/76411", 
        value = "Maintenance", id = "76411"), .Names = c("self", 
    "value", "id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        self = ".../rest/api/2/customFieldOption/76412", 
        value = "New Feature", id = "76412"), .Names = c("self", 
    "value", "id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "fields.created", 
"fields.customfield_10303", "fields.customfield_28100"))
```

Comment: Can you please provide your data or a dummy?

Comment: I cannot flatten to write it out. I provided a screen of the nested df. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: have you tried ```dput(your_data)``` to provide us with it?

Comment: Added. I am only interested in the "value" data. Ex "New Feature"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(Group=c("A","A","B","C","D","D"),
       Batman=1:6,
       Superman=c("red","blue","orange","red","blue","red"))

nested <- df %>%
  nest(data=-Group)

unnested <- nested %>%
  unnest(data)
```

Nesting and unnesting data with tidyr

```r
library(purrr)
nested %>%
  mutate(data=map(data,~select(.x,2))) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

select with purrr, but lapply as you've done is fine, it's just for aesthetics ;)

Comment: I think you meant  nest(key=-Group) ?

Comment: @Ken As for the nesting direction, the left side of the equality defines the name of the nested column (if you've got a recent tidyr version)

Comment: I'll have to check my version. I keep getting "Error in nest(., data = -Group) : object 'Group' not found".

Comment: My first code was just an example of nesting bur your data are already nested ;) if you want to nest 2 columns called a and b put nest(a,b)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this.

First, instead of changing the data, I added a column with mutate. Then, directly selected the same column from all nested lists. Then, I converted the list column into a vector. Finally, I cleaned it up by removing the other columns.

It seems to work. I don't know yet how it will handle multiple rows within the nested df.

```
   dat <- sample_dat %>% 
   mutate(cats = sapply(nested_col, `[[`, 2)) %>% 
   mutate(categories = sapply(cats, toString)) %>% 
   select(-nested_col, -cats)
```

**Related**

- [How to directly select the same column from all nested lists within a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016359/how-to-directly-select-the-same-column-from-all-nested-lists-within-a-list)
- [r-convert list column into character vector where lists are characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174438/r-convert-list-column-into-character-vector-where-lists-are-characters)

Comment: ah you want to do that. Theres also an unnest function in tidyr. But your post wasn't clear

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I struggled to articulate that one. That double mutate pipe is uuuuugly. Do you mind posting a version using unnest? I tried several times but was unsuccessful. Happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks!